# Looking up values in 3 different columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Where county name in column A matches county name in column E, how can I write a formula in excel that would place the corresponding county ID from column F in cell B2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to look it up, it would be a `VLOOKUP` like so:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E:E,A2)>0,VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand how your data is organized, but if you just want to check for equality (within a row) of Col. A and Col. E, returning the value in F if the values match, then a simple `=IF(Condition, Result if True, Result if False)` should work:

`=IF(A1 = E1, F1, "")`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to add a fourth column, let's say X, with formulas like `=IF($A1=$E1;1;0)`
And then in B2 you use a simple lookup to find the 1-value: `=LOOKUP(1;X2:X8;F2:F8)`